# How to create python virtualenv through userdata in an Amazon EC2 (Amazon Linux 2) instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

How to create python **virtual environment** in **ec2-instances**?

I am try to create virtual environment in ec2-instances while i am creating ec2-instances so need to imporve the code on **user-data**.

**User-data**  is nothing but it will be used **before** creating **instances** we can send the **script/code** to newly creating ec2-instances.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code to create virtual environment using **user-data** in aws **ec2-instances**.

**#!/bin/bash**

**sudo yum update**

**sudo yum install python3 pip3 -y**

**sudo pip3 install --upgrade pip**

**pip install --upgrade pip**

**python3 -m venv /home/ec2-user/workspace**

**workspace** is virtual environment name